# What is the red bar in the UI for?

Tags: death-stranding

I was riding my bike along and this UI element appeared and I don't know how to clear it. I tried drinking from my Cantine, but I think that's for Stamina which is the blue bar.

[image: Red bar ui]

What is this red bar telling me about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's your blood level/HP. If you get injured, it goes down. Using hemetic grenades and ammo also cause it to go down. Going down to zero causes a voidout (i.e. the "explosion" that happens at the end of the tutorial). You need to keep up your blood levels by equipping blood packs and eating cryptobiotes.

Comment: Why does it show up even though I am at 1000/1000 HP? Is it just showing the Blood Bad amount?

Comment: It sometimes shows up when you're at rest, but it's been a while since I've played. You might want to check your game settings.